# Is it possible to convert language specific characters to latin characters in UTF8

Tags: unicode, c#-4.0

I am wondering if there are any relationships or existing algorithms allowing converting from national characters to equivalent Latin characters within the UTF8 codepage?

For example (in Polish):

Ą -> A

Ó -> O

ż -> z

ź -> z
...

phrase like: 'zażółć gęślą jażń'

converts to: 'zazolc gesla jazn'

Currently I am using a conversion array for Polish, but I am looking for a universal solution handling all Latin based languages.

Thanks

Comment: Update: I need to do it within a .NET application and work with string variables. This is a one way conversion so there is no need to store any additional information as Pooli suggested. Thanks.

Comment: At first check if you really need to strip accents. There is no real 'equivalent' Latin character, you always loose information this way. But if you do, there are some ways like the iconv library or stuff like unicode decomposition.

Comment: Thanks schlenk. Unicode decomposition seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: But I hope you do realize that is damaging the language, right? Those are stand-alone characters with meaning, not just A or O with a squiggle. Imagine someone asking: How do I map R -> P and Q -> O (Q is just O with a squiggle, after all).

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/iconvnet/

In general, search for something called iconv

Answer (score 1):

To make the answer complete, the 'Unicode decomposition + C#' led me to this CodeProject article (codeproject.com/KB/cs/UnicodeNormalization.aspx?display=Print) which offers a ready to use solution. The ability to name what you are looking for can't be underestimated ;) Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure that this is a definitive answer that you will need, but when I've had to do this in the past, I've converted all 'special' characters into a named or numerical entity so that they are protected during the conversion process.